# Laravel Blade Templating @foreach order

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Is there any way to sort `@foreach` loop in laravel blade?

```
@foreach ($specialist as $key)
  <option value="{{$key->specialist_id}}"> {{$key->description}}</option>
@endforeach
```

I wolud like to order by `$key->description`,

I know I can use order by in my controller,

```
->orderBy('description')
```

but the controller returns other values and those values must be sorted as well, so I need to order by in blade.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming that your $specialist variable is an Eloquent collection, you can do:

```
@foreach ($specialist->sortBy('description') as $oneSpecialist)
  <option value="{{ $oneSpecialist->specialist_id }}"> {{ $oneSpecialist->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Moreover, you could call your Eloquent model directly from the template:

```
@foreach (Specialist::all()->sortBy('description') as $oneSpecialist)
  <option value="{{ $oneSpecialist->specialist_id }}"> {{ $oneSpecialist->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Note that you are using a misleading variable name of $key in your foreach() loop. Your $key is actually an array item, not a key. I assume that you saw foreach ($array as $key => $value) syntax somewhere and then removed the $value?

Comment: How to sort by a property in a pivot table

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a laravel [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections). More specifically, the [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby). You can use either of these in your view or the controller that you are passing the data from. If the data is being passed by a model, be sure to use the `collect()` function before proceeding to use any of the others listed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to write sortBy in view blade?
just like   $sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');  or need write in the javasctipt?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the order fails you can use `->values()` to re-index the elements

```
$collection->sortBy('key')->values()
```